# How to create a weighted 2D histogram

Tags: python, matlab, histogram

A weighted 1D histogram seems pretty straight-forward. How can I implement a 2D weighted histogram given a weights-vector, *w*?

MATLAB:

```
x = randn(4,1);            //some random x input
y = randn(4,1);            //some random y input
w = [10, 20, 30, 40];      //weight to be assigned to corresponding data point in the generated histogram, i.e. the pixel intensity value

figure;
H = histogram2(x,y);   //Matlab built-in 2D histogram
```

How should I use *w* in the above code snippet to get a weighted 2D histogram function.

*MATLAB code is preferred, but may also accept Python.

Comment: Hi. This is not very clear, for instance, if you have 4 value pairs, why use 64 NBINS? In any case, is the solution not as simple as x=x.*w; y=y.*w; ? this way the first rows get lower weight etc.

Comment: Not quite. x, y should give the projected coordinate after histogram transformation. The actual pixel value of each data point in that 2D plane should take a corresponding w value. As for the bin, I have simplified the problem by removing Nbin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my weighted 2d histogram I took from some old code of mine...

```
function f  = hist2dw(x,y,weights,xedges,yedges)
%all inputs should be vectors
[~,xbin] = histc(x,xedges);
[~,ybin] = histc(y,yedges);

xbin(xbin==0) = inf;
ybin(ybin==0) = inf;
xnbin = numel(xedges);
ynbin = numel(yedges);

xy = xbin * ynbin + ybin;

[xyu,id] = unique(xy);
xyu(end) = []; % remove Inf bin
id(end) = [];
hstres = histc(xy,xyu);
hstres = hstres.*weights(id); % add the weights to the histogram
f(ynbin,xnbin)=0; % preallocate memory
f(xyu-ynbin) = hstres;
```

and here's an example on how to use it:

```
x = rand(1000,1);
y = rand(1000,1);
w=[ones(900,1) ; 5*ones(100,1) ];
edg=0:0.01:1;

imagesc(edg,edg,hist2dw(x(:),y(:),w(:),edg,edg));colorbar
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks bla, your code output looks good. However, instead of just dumping your function into my program, could you please explain what's going on? Or even better -- for the benefits of future solution-seekers -- simplify the solution to match the original problem in it's form?

Comment: lets first see where we should begin with, do you understand what `histc` doest?

Comment: I understand what it does.

Comment: so where does it needs explaining?

Comment: I think this code is not correct; It is multiplying the final histogram by one scalar weight each. A weighted histogram would need to sum up the weights for all data points included in each bin. I'm suspect that, at best, this will just use the weight from the first datum in each bin, rather than summing over all data in each bin—unless Matlab is doing something alarmingly clever.